# Gitlab CI in docker. Disable cleaning directory before stage starts

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I decided to build my pipeline on this plan:

1. Build stage: Run only if the branch is the main one or one of my build files has been modified. It inherits `docker:latest`, and builds a test-ready container (pytest, lint) and pushes it to the local registry.
2. Test stage: always runs, inherits the latest or own branch container from the previous stage. All tests are run in it.
3. Push to production: it doesn't matter now.

**Problems** in 2 stage:

I run the `ls -la` command and I don't see my `venv, node_modules` folders. I thought `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS` would solve my problem. But it didn't help.

How reproduce the problem:

Building image

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ARG CI_PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $CI_PROJECT_DIR
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg CI_PROJECT_DIR=$CI_PROJECT_DIR .
```

Test

```yaml
lint:
  variables:
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  stage: test
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -lah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `CI_PROJECT_DIR`. Save your code in another directory:
`/my-app` for example.
And in your second stage use `cd /my-app`.

Code example of your second stage:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - test
  before_script:
    - cd /my-app
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -lah
```